# Spring Boot 2: test secured endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, junit5

I have a project build up with spring boot 2 (data, rest, security...), so in the project I have rest controllers like this:

```
@RestController
class ProductController {

private final ProductService productService;
private final ProductConverter productConverter;
private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
ProductController(ProductService productService,
                  ProductConverter productConverter,
                  UserService userService) {
    this.productService = productService;
    this.productConverter = productConverter;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@GetMapping(EndpointPath.PRODUCTS)
PageableProductsDTO getProducts(Principal principal, Pageable pageable) {
    return productService.getUsersProducts(principal.getName(), pageable);
}

@PostMapping(EndpointPath.PRODUCT)
ResponseEntity<?> createNewProduct(@Valid @RequestBody ProductDetailsDto productDetailsDto, Principal principal) {
   productService.saveProduct(productConverter.createFrom(productDetailsDto), principal.getName());
   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
}
```

and also security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final RESTLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
public ResourceServerConfig(RESTLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler) {
    this.restLogoutSuccessHandler = restLogoutSuccessHandler;
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .anonymous()
                .disable()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl(EndpointPath.SIGN_OUT)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(GET, EndpointPath.PRODUCTS).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(POST, EndpointPath.PRODUCT).authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}
}
```

Also I coverde *ProductController* with unit tests like this:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessageSourceConfiguration.class})
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class ProductControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Mock
private ProductService productService;

@Mock
private ProductConverter productConverter;

@Mock
private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ProductController(productService, productConverter, userService))
                                              .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
                                              .setControllerAdvice(new ControllerAdvice(messageSource)).build();
}

@Test
void shouldReturnSetOfProducts() throws Exception {
    // Given
    String authenticatedUserEmail = "email@g.com";
    when(productService.getUsersProducts(eq(authenticatedUserEmail), ArgumentMatchers.any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(new PageableProductsDTO(new PageImpl<>(
                                                                        List.of(new ProductDetailsDto("1234", "name", 1), new ProductDetailsDto("12345", "name 2", 2)))));

    // When - Then
    mockMvc.perform(get(EndpointPath.PRODUCTS).principal(() -> authenticatedUserEmail).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productDtos.content", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productDtos.totalPages", is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productDtos.totalElements", is(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productDtos.content.[*].barcode", containsInAnyOrder("1234", "12345")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productDtos.content.[*].name", containsInAnyOrder("name", "name 2")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productDtos.content.[*].price", containsInAnyOrder(1, 2)));
}
}
```

beside that unit tests I want to make sure that the endpoint **EndpointPath.PRODUCTS** is secured. Does anybody know how to write a unit test for this? For example: expected status 401/403 when user is not authenticated/authorized.

Comment: Write a case without auth, trigger the API and expect status -401/403 and test your 401/403 response too

Answer (score 1):

The simplest test, full on Spring Boot integration test, would look like this

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DisplayName("sample boot integration tests")
public class SpringBootIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @DisplayName("pages are secured")
    void pageIsSecure() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/products")
        )
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("http://localhost/login"))
            .andExpect(unauthenticated())
        ;
    }
}
```

Typically you will not see a 401/403 if there is no authentication. Cause Spring Security will redirect you to the authorization server.

The `redirectUrl` would be something that matches the redirect to the authorization server.

So it could be something like

```
    redirectedUrl(containsString("http://authorization.server/oauth/authorize"))
```

If you have an endpoint that expects a token, you could do something like this in your test

```
    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
    .andExpect(unauthenticated())
```